# Node JS, exporting a class and cosumin it with different name

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node v14.4.0. I created a file and named it 'dao.js'. The file includes the following:

```
class AppDAO {
    // some constructor and functions
}
module.exports = AppDAO
```

In my app.js file I load it using

```
const dao =  require('./dao');
const db = new dao();
```

It works fine, but I don't know why, shouldn't I use the class name as I set it, "AppDAO", instead of "dao"?

This [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) as well as other links, do not help me in understanding how require modules works. 
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You mean in `app.js`? You can give it whatever name you like - you're just assigning the result of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

file dao.js

```js
class AppDAO {
    // some constructor and functions
}
exports.AppDAO = AppDAO;
```

and in app.js

```js
const dao =  require('./dao');
const db = new dao.AppDAO();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the class from the file you are requiring, so you have to write it like this.

```
const dao =  require('./dao');
const db = new dao.AppDAO();
```

Comment: Bu it works fine as I wrote: const moshe =  require('./dao'); const db = new moshe(userInput.filePath);